# There is a way to capture the response of a child process in linux terminal?

Tags: linux, terminal, parent-child, ubuntu-20.04, strace

I'm trying to install a software. When executing the `setup.sh` it calls another compiled file `linux.installer` which apparently calls a bash command, followed by this error:

```
ERROR: Cannot wait for process "/media/virtualCD/installGUI" "-CDPath" "media/virtualCD/linux"
```

Stranger it turns out, that when I run this same command line on my own (an actual copy and paste in terminal): the installGUI runs perfectly (after declaring some environment variables).

So, I would like to know which is the response of `"/media/virtualCD/installGUI" "-CDPath" "media/virtualCD/linux"` into the "enviroment" of the parent process `linux.installer`. Because there is, evidently, some difference between both running this command line in terminal or running it by `linux.installer`.

I tried with `ltrace`, `strace`. I finded out which environment variables and libraries were involved. But I would like to know which would be the response of this command line as if I were into the "`linux.installer` terminal".

There is some way to debbug this?

Comment: You could probably go into the setup.sh file, find where the sub process is being called, and direct its output to a file of your choosing?

Comment: The problem is that setup.sh calls "linux.installer" (a compiled file). And linux.installer is actually, the one that calls "/media/virtualCD/installGUI" "-CDPath" "media/virtualCD/linux". In fact, my problem is to find a way to know how this compiled file is calling this command line, as I would be finding in a .sh file as you said.

Comment: ` to find a way to know how this compiled file is calling this command` - if you do not have the source file of the compiled file, you will be unable to tell this with out it.

One thing that stands out is the second path `media/virtualCD/linux`, which is not an absolute path (meaning /media/virtualCD/linux), and is probably what's causing the error, but of course we can only speculate since there is not a lot of info here.

You said when you run it from command line, it works...after you declare a few variables? What are those variables? Do they relate to a path possibly?